# Lehmer’s totient problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, model-theory

Euler’s totient function $\varphi$ is a function defined over $\mathbb{N}$ so that $\varphi(n)=|\{m\mid m<n\wedge (m,n)=1\}|$.

Now [Lehmer’s totient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem) asks whether $n$ is prime iff $\varphi(n)$ divides $n-1$.

I am curious whether the question can be expressed as a question in ring language. More specifically, whether there is a firs order formula $\psi(x)$ in the ring language so that $\mathbb{Z}\models \psi(n)$ if and only if $\varphi(n)$ divides $n-1$.

**Remark** As James pointed out, the question has a positive answer. But what I really want is an algebraic answer. Probably the question was not in a proper shape. How about this:

Whether there is a first order formula $\psi(x,y)$ in  the ring language so that there is theory $A$ extending axioms of ring theory in a proper way (which is not necessary consistent with theory of $\mathbb{Z}$) so that

(1).  $ A\vdash\forall x\exists y\psi(x,y)\wedge (\forall x \forall y(\psi(x,y)\rightarrow( y\mbox{ divides } x-1\leftrightarrow x\mbox{ is prime})) ) $;  and

(2). For all $m$ and $n$, $\mathbb{Z}\models \psi(n,m)$ if and only if $m=\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Would it work to say something like: there exist $x_1,\dotsc,x_6$ such that $n-m=x_1^2+\dotsb+x_4^2$, $n\neq m$, and $mx_5+nx_6=1$?

Comment: For the new question, let $\alpha$ be any sentence true in $\mathbb Z$ that is independent of the theory of rings, let $\psi_0(x,y)$ be any formula defining $y=\varphi(x)$ in $\mathbb Z$ as in James’s answer, and put $\psi(x,y)=\psi_0(x,y)\land\alpha$ and $A={}$ the theory of rings ${}+\neg\alpha$.

Comment: Why (1) is satisfied?

Comment: Because in $A$, $\psi(x,y)$ implies a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I will rule out this weird case.

Comment: This is not going to help. Put, say, $\psi_1(x,y)=(x\text{ is prime}\land y=1)\lor(x\text{ is not prime}\land y=0)$ and $\psi(x,y)=(\alpha\land\psi_0(x,y))\lor(\neg\alpha\land\psi_1(x,y))$.

Comment: Hmm.. Nice solution. Currently I have no clue how to exclude these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Every computable relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ can be defined with a first-order formula in the language of rings.

The idea is to "arithmetize" computation: encode Turing machines and their states as natural numbers in such a way that the basic operations like changing the state of the head, writing a bit, etc. are all given by arithemtic relations. This is the basis of Kleene's proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem (Godel's proof used the arithmetization of syntax, rather than computation).

Comment: Ah, you are right. But this is not what I want. I need a natural way to translate this.

Comment: If you are changing your question, you should do that as an edit to the body of the question, not as a comment on an answer. Or, you should post a new question, asking what you now realize you ought to have asked (and linking each question to the other).

Comment: @喻良 If you do wish to edit a question or ask a new one with clarification, then you should explain what you mean with "natural".

Comment: I  accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For a more algebraic approach, we can add $\phi$ to the language of rings, and then state Lehmer's conjecture as:

$$(\text{axiom for } \phi)\ \&\ \phi(n)|(n-1) \implies Prime(n)$$

Here $Prime$ is one of a few defintions in the language of rings alone:

\begin{align}
x|y &:= \exists u \ ux=y \\
Prime(p) &:= \forall t\ t|p \implies p|t \vee t|1 \\
Power(p,q) &:= \forall t\  t|q \implies p|t \vee t|1 \\
RelPrime(q,r) &:= \forall t\ t|q\ \&\ t|r \implies t|1 \\
PosPrime(p) &:= Prime(p) \ \& \ \phi(p)=p-1
\end{align}

And the axiom for $\phi$ is the universally quantified conjunction of

\begin{align}
(p=0) \vee (p|1) &\implies \phi(p)=p\\
Prime(p) &\implies \exists u\ u|1 \ \& \ \phi(up)=up-1 \\
Power(p,q) &\implies \phi(pq)=p \phi(q) \\
RelPrime(q,r) &\implies \phi(qr)=\phi(q)\phi(r) \\
\end{align}

If $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the conjecture, we can ask what induction axioms are necessary to prove it.

In any case, we can ask what other rings have functions $\phi$ which satisfy the conjecture in one of these forms.

**Update:**  To make this more recognizable as Lehman's conjecture, we should also ensure that the axioms determine the value of $\phi$ for every element in $\mathbb{Z}$. The axioms above leave open whether $\phi(2)=2-1$ or $\phi(-2)=-2-1$, which lead to $\phi(2)=1$ or $\phi(2)=3$ respectively. The values of $\phi$ for 3 and higher primes are also independent of this axiom and this choice.

We have at least three ways to determine $\phi$ completely in $\mathbb{Z}$ if we want to:  *either* by 
adding the infinite set of axioms
$$\{ PosPrime(2),\ PosPrime(3),\ PosPrime(5),\ PosPrime(7),\ \ldots\}$$
*or* by working with ordered rings and using the axiom
$$1<p\ \&\ Prime(p) \implies PosPrime(p)$$
*or* by adding the single axiom 
$$PosPrime(2) \ \&\ PosPrime(3) \ \&\ PosPrime(5)
\ \&\ \Big(Prime(p+q+r) \implies$$
$$(PosPrime(p) \ \&\ PosPrime(q) \ \&\ PosPrime(r)) \implies PosPrime(p+q+r)\Big)$$

I like the single axiom, but you can decide which gives the conjecture the most ring-theoretic look.

Comment: Thanks, this does look more algebraic. However, as you said, to prove $\phi$ is exactly Euler's function, we need some  complex induction axioms. Is there definition of $\varphi$ so that Lehmer's problem holds for the polynomial ring over $Q$?

Comment: I think there is a definition of $\phi$ which makes this hold in $Q[x]$; let $\phi(q)=q$ for $q\in Q$, and $\phi(p(x))=p(x)-1$ for any monic irreducible $p$.  But it would hold trivially because the hypothesis $\phi(p)|p-1$ would only be satisfied in the trivial cases.